# Отображение страницы своего сайта в facebook приложении

Tags: facebook, facebook-api, facebooksdk

Можно ли в facebook приложении отображать страницу внешнего сайта (например: mysite.com). Что бы при входе в facebook приложение был виден интерфейс моей страницы. Или с fb приложения делать запросы на api моего сайта, что бы получить с него данные и отобразить в этом fb приложении и при этом написать необходимый мне фронтенд? Если есть такая возможность, то сбросьте ссылку на документацию. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется Page Tab и работает через iframe
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/page-tab-dialog

Comment: Вы уверены, что данная информация актуальна? сейчас следуя этому туториалу невозможно сделать, что-либо подобное

Comment: @mkletsko обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! это то, что мне нужно

Comment: @mkletsko Если ответ решил вашу проблему отметьте его как решение.